# Why permission denied for npx prisma generate?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I am using postgres Prisma for the database management. So while  firing the cmd of npx prisma generate i faced this error:

```
node_modules/.bin/prisma: Permission denied
```

any solution for this ???

I tried `ALTER USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password';`
to define a role for the user and ger permission to access database.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you invoke `npx prisma db pull` command?